# Access Data from an External API into a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm need help getting the data from the gitHuburl object to display onto the screen. I've also tried in the curly bracket to do {userData.media.title} but that didnt work for me either.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

//githuburl variable to = the url
const gitHubUrl = "https://hubspotwebteam.github.io/CodeExercise/src/js/data/data.json";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getGitHubUserWithFetch();
  }, []);

 // fetching data from the url above
  const getGitHubUserWithFetch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(gitHubUrl);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    setUserData(jsonData);
  };

  // displaying it onto the page with this code
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2>Movies to watch</h2>
      </header>
      <div className="user-container">
        <h5 className="info-item">{userData.title}</h5>
        <h5 className="info-item">{userData.year}</h5>
        <h5 className="info-item">{userData.poster}</h5>
        <h5 className="info-item">{userData.genre}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[here is a link to an image that shows the css but not that data that won't show from the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcZ5.png)

Comment: Hi Kelley. Please include details on what exactly is going wrong. "having trouble" and "didn't work for me either" don't give users a lot to go on. If there's an error message, please include it in its entirety.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question to be more clear. I also added an image to show that I'm trying to display data from another url on the page. But its only showing the CSS and items in the h2 tag.

Comment: Hi Kelley, please check my answer if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Ayaz I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to display the records as the url mention in the question returns a collection. There are few issues in the code as mentioned.

- userData state should be an array instead of object.
- Set jsonData.media instead of jsonData in `setUserData(jsonData.media);`
- Use `Array.prototype.map` to display the data in jsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    //githuburl variable to = the url
    const gitHubUrl = "https://hubspotwebteam.github.io/CodeExercise/src/js/data/data.json";

    function App() {
      const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        getGitHubUserWithFetch();
      }, []);

     // fetching data from the url above
      const getGitHubUserWithFetch = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(gitHubUrl);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setUserData(jsonData.media);
      };

      // displaying it onto the page with this code
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h2>Movies to watch</h2>
          </header>
          <>
          {
              userData.map(u => 
                <>
              <div className="user-container">
                <h5 className="info-item">{u.title}</h5>
                <h5 className="info-item">{u.year}</h5>
                <h5 className="info-item">{u.poster}</h5>
                <h5 className="info-item">{u.genre}</h5>
              </div>
              <hr />
           </>
            )
        }
          </>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a map to show list of data

> Best place to learn them is
> [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

[Here is the solution for your Q](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-star-4gyyp?file=/src/App.js)

- Add .css accordingly